# Receiving error(*errors.errorString) *{s: "pq: unexpected DataRow in simple query execution"}

Tags: postgresql, go

The error

```
(*errors.errorString) *{s: "pq: unexpected DataRow in simple query execution"}
```

appears after the line with the commentary. Didn't find any solution online. Since stackoverflow asks for more details, this is an update query that is supposed to update a todo and a list of subtasks in the database. The exact error is in the question topic. I post the complete code for the function that returns the error.

```golang
func (t *TodoTable) UpdateTodo(ctx context.Context, todo *Todo, t_id int) error {

    tx, err := t.sqlxdb.BeginTxx(ctx, &sql.TxOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    rollback_err := func(err error) error {
        if err2 := tx.Rollback(); err2 != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("%v; %v", err, err2)
        }
        return err
    }

    row := tx.QueryRowxContext(ctx, "UPDATE todos SET todo_name=$1, deadline=$2, updated_at=$3 WHERE todo_id=$4 returning todo_id", todo.TodoName, todo.Deadline, todo.UpdatedAt, t_id)
    if row.Err() != nil {
        return rollback_err(err)
    }

    var subs_ids []int

    // Getting subs ids from database
    query := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT sub_id FROM subs WHERE todo_id=%d", t_id)

    // THE ERROR COMES AFTER EXECUTING THE LINE BELOW

    rows, err := tx.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        rollback_err(err)
    }
    if rows != nil {
        for rows.Next() {
            var sub_id int
            err = rows.Scan(&sub_id)
            if err != nil {
                rollback_err(err)
            }
            subs_ids = append(subs_ids, sub_id)
        }

        if err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
            return rollback_err(err)
        }
    }

    // Updating subs
    for i, sub := range todo.Subs {
        _, err = tx.ExecContext(ctx, fmt.Sprintf("UPDATE subs SET sub_name='%s' WHERE sub_id=%d", sub.Sub_name, subs_ids[i]))
        if err != nil {
            return rollback_err(err)
        }
    }

    return nil

}
```

Comment: The error actually [comes from PostgreSQL](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/conn.go#L729). Looks like you cannot have multiple active queries with not completely fetched result sets active in parallel on the same connection—see [this discussion](https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/81#issuecomment-21192655).

Comment: Dang.. This looks like a pretty basic thing - to update a table and another one that is connected to it. What would be the workaround then? Can you outline it?

Comment: I have little exposure to PostgreSQL, unfortunately. So basically what I was able to dug up is at the limits of my understanding these matters, sorry ;-)

Comment: You're trying to execute a query on an already committed transaction, what's up with that? Also the way you use `rollback_err` (in two places at least) is a very bad idea, like you execute it but then you keep going like nothing happened.